# Qual a melhor maneira de uma Activity chamar a si mesma?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

O app exibe questões aleatórias seguindo como modelo a `QuestionsActivity`, ou seja, o usuário escolhe verdadeiro ou falso e só irá mudar a questão (`textView`) e o design da tela permanecerá o mesmo. As minhas questões estão num `AsyncTask`, a ordem delas é aleatoria e não deve se repetir porém chamo essa AsyncTask no `onCreate` da minha `QuestionsActivity`. Isso vai dar o maior bug. Como faço para acessar "recursivamente" minha `QuestionsActivity` de uma maneira que só instancie o meu AsyncTask UMA vez (no momento que abre o App)?

Comment: O que você pode fazer é ao invés de ter que criar uma Activity nova (ou recriar a mesma) para cada tela (questão), se o layout e a funções (funcionalidades) do aplicativo for o mesmo para todas a questões e só trocar o conteúdo da questão, você pode não recriar a Activity toda, mas sim sortear a nova questão restaurar estado original da tela e tocar os valores.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode implementar a sua classe AsyncTask utilizando o padrão [Singleton](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton). Dessa maneira, você garante que durante a execução da sua aplicação haverá somente uma instância do AsyncTask.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public class MySingleton {

      // Variavel estática que conterá a instancia do AsyncTask     
      private static MySingleton instance;

     // Construtor privado. Suprime o construtor público padrao.
     private MySingleton() {

     }

     // Método público estático de acesso único ao objeto!
     public static MySingleton getInstance(){

           if(instance == NULL){
                // Uma nova instancia é criada e retornada para quem está //pedindo
               instance = new MySingleton();
           }

          // Retorna o a instância do objeto
          return instance;
     }
}
```

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi muito bem a pergunta. Você quer saber se o ArrayList sempre vai ficar na mesma configuração? Ou seja, independente de realizar um shuffle nele, ele sempre vai se manter no estado inicial?

Comment: Removi a anterior porque não ficou claro. Abro app e activity será inicializada, clico no botão e será feito um novo objeto dessa mesma activity (o anterior será limpado pelo garbageCollection). O AsyncTask é acessado pela própria activity, ou seja, apesar do Singleton uma nova instacia será feita pois a anterior não existe mais. (Não serão duas na mesma execução)

Comment: Talvez a melhor forma seja obter todas as questões e ir trocando o textView a medida que o usuário clica no botão "próximo". Obrigada, votei p fechar essa questão!

Comment: Ok, mas de qualquer forma você deve levar em consideração que, independente de você destruir a activity ou não, apenas uma instância do AsyncTask irá existir.

Comment: Nesse caso, não irá existir nenhum objeto do AsyncTask? Já que o objeto era da activity e esta foi destruida

Comment: Como o AsyncTask é uma variável estática da classe Singleton, sempre haverá uma única variável AsyncTask  e ela será igual para todos os objetos da classe Singleton. Dessa forma, se você criar um objeto "A" Singleton, setar um AsyncTask para ele e depois adestruír "A", o AsyncTask não será destruído, afinal, como foi dito, o AsyncTask é estático.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22565/discussion-between-regmoraes-and-daniela-marques-de-morais).